# Почему getch ncurses вызывает segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

Linux mint, XTerm

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iosfwd>

using namespace std;

WINDOW* create_win(int height, int width, int beginy, int beginx, short color = 1, char* title = nullptr);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int height, width;
    int ch;
    WINDOW* input;
    WINDOW* ami;
    WINDOW* hdb3;
    char line[width];

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    curs_set(1);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);
    start_color();
    refresh();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_WHITE);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_YELLOW);

    {//initialize windows
        int ih = 3;
        int ah = (height-3)/2;
        int hh = (height-3)/2;
        input = create_win(ih,width,0,0);
        ami = create_win(ah,width,ih,0,2,"AMI");
        hdb3 = create_win(hh,width,ih+ah,0,2,"HDB3");
    }


    ch= getch();//Проблема тут

    while (ch!=27) { //Если убрать эти 4 строки ch = getch() и цикл ошибки нет
        getstr(line);
    }

    //Create charts

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

WINDOW* create_win(int height, int width, int beginy, int beginx, short color, char* title) {
    WINDOW* local;
    local = newwin(height, width, beginy, beginx);
    wbkgd(local, COLOR_PAIR(color));
    wclear(local);
    box(local, 0, 0);
    wattron(local, A_REVERSE);
    mvwaddstr(local, 0, 1, title);
    wrefresh(local);
    return local;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как у Вас такое компилируется должно быть предупреждение? Объявление  массивов неизвестного на момент компиляции размера недопустимо же.

```
    int height, width; 
    char line[width];
```

Память для `line` не выделяется. Фактически это эквивалентно

```
    int height, width = 0;
    char line[0];
```

Возможно поэтому при вызове `getstr(line)` возникает segmentation fault.

Выделите память явным образом:

```
    #define SIZE_WIDTH   256
    char line[SIZE_WIDTH];
    ...
    getstr(line);
```

Comment: нет, если убрать цикл и в конец `getch()` поставить, то ошибки нет, ошибка связана с `getch()`. Память не могу посмотреть, дебагер какой-то тухлый в `netbeans`

Comment: Если убрать строку `getstr(line);` Ошибки нет ?

Comment: Похоже что нет, попробовал `ch = getch();
    
    while(ch!=27) {
        if (ch == KEY_F(1))
            mvaddstr(6,6,"dasdadsad");
    }
`
Строка не рисуется `keypad(stdscr, TRUE);` вначале есть

Comment: Если ошибки нет , то логично предположить, что ошибка в `getstr(line);`

Comment: Так это стандартная функция `ncurses`

Comment: Конечно , тока Вы передаете ее `getstr(NULL);` Поэтому ошибка.

Comment: ну так а как я еще считаю строку вводимую. Она в неё её и запишет

Comment: Выделите память и считайте в эту память,  строку.

Comment: Компилируется потому что VLA в силе (как расширение). Ну и отсутствие инициализации дает неопределенное значение, а не 0.

Comment: @Yaroslav "тока Вы передаете ее getstr(NULL)" - нет. Переменная `width` инициализируется после вызова `getmaxyx()`, поэтому в `getstr()` передаётся нормальное значение. Но каков при этом размер `line` - да, вопрос другой :)

Comment: В этом и ошибка  ,  размер `line` неизвестен , но адрес есть.